# After Crittercism update to 5.6.2, compiler error "Could not build module 'Crittercism'" appeared

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios10, crittercism

I have performed pod update for Crittercism to latest version 5.6.2 and my project has compiler error shown in screen-shot.[image]

FYI : I am checking my project in Xcode 8.

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap your Pod files with appropriate targets.

```
target “TARGET_NAME” do
    pod 'XYZ', '~> 1.'
end
```

Follow this steps:

1. Remove pod
2. Clean Derived data.
3. Re-install pod again.

This should clear the error, since declaration is correct.

UPDATE: Try adding New line to CrittercismSDK/CrittercismVersion.h

```
#define CRITTERCISM_VERSION @"5.6.2"[Hit enter here. Unlock and save the file.]
```